# How do I install MongoDB 3.0 in Vivid?

Tags: software-installation, java, mongodb

The official vivid package for mongodb is 2.x, and the packages that MongoDB provide themselves on http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/trusty/ are only available for LTS releases.

An alternative is that I could switch back to 14.04 LTS, but I would need to install openjdk-8-jdk, which is only available for vivid.

Comment: I think nothing bad will happen if you install it from trusty repo to vivid.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's possible, that MongoDB doesn't start if you use the Trusty packages:

```
Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
```

In this case, install the ***Debian Wheezy*** packages as described at the end.

### Install the Trusty DEB packages

**Download the DEB files**

```
cd
wget http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/trusty/mongodb-org/3.0/multiverse/binary-amd64/mongodb-org-mongos_3.0.3_amd64.deb
wget http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/trusty/mongodb-org/3.0/multiverse/binary-amd64/mongodb-org-server_3.0.3_amd64.deb
wget http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/trusty/mongodb-org/3.0/multiverse/binary-amd64/mongodb-org-shell_3.0.3_amd64.deb
wget http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/trusty/mongodb-org/3.0/multiverse/binary-amd64/mongodb-org-tools_3.0.3_amd64.deb
wget http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/trusty/mongodb-org/3.0/multiverse/binary-amd64/mongodb-org_3.0.3_amd64.deb
```

**And install with (in this order)**

```
sudo dpkg -i mongodb-org-server_3.0.3_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i mongodb-org-tools_3.0.3_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i mongodb-org-shell_3.0.3_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i mongodb-org-mongos_3.0.3_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i mongodb-org_3.0.3_amd64.deb
```

And taken from the comments, thank you [@Pilot6](https://askubuntu.com/users/167850/pilot6):

> They may have dependencies to each other. That's why installation
>   packages one by one may give errors. I suggest `sudo dpkg -i mongodb*.deb`

---

### Use the Trusty PPA

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

---

### Use the Debian Wheezy packages

It's possible, that MongoDB doesn't start if you use the Trusty packages:

```
Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
```

In this case, install the ***Debian Wheezy*** packages as described below

```
sudo apt-get remove mongodb-org
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
sudo echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian wheezy/mongodb-org/3.0 main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

Comment: They may have dependencies to each other. That's why installation packages one by one may give errors. I suggest `sudo dpkg -i mongodb*.deb`

Comment: @Pilot6 Therefore `sudo dpkg -i mongodb-org_3.0.3_amd64.deb` as last command

Comment: Just a suggestion. And it is easier as one command. If you install multiple packages in one command, dependencies are resolved.

Comment: @Pilot6 added and linked =)

Comment: Ok, I used the Trusty deb packages and it worked. How do I then get it running as a service so that I can start and stop it using `service mongod start`?

Comment: Yes `sudo service mongod start`

Comment: If that doesn't work, use the steps for the wheezy packages.

Answer (score 4):

Successfully installed with mongo version 3.0.6 in my Ubuntu 15.04 using debian wheezy repository - see below steps

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10`

`echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian wheezy/mongodb-org/3.0 main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org`

However, after all the steps above and mongodb installed in my machine, now when I  tried to start the mongodb service with `sudo service mongod start` it would fail. Throwing the following error message

`Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service failed to load: No such file or directory.`

**So here is how I resolved and startup mongodb normally**

- Change MongoDB's default data store files from **/var/lib/mongodb** to **/data/db**
- `sudo mkdir -p /data/db`
- `sudo gedit /etc/mongod.conf` and change the “dbpath” line as below
- Replace **dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb**   TO   **dbpath=/data/db** and then save the file.
- Then delete the old default /var/lib/mongodb
- Now we must make all the directories/files owned by mongod user
- Run `sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /data/db`

**And now finally I can start mongo with `sudo service mongod start`**

And chcek that the service is running with `sudo systemctl status mongod`  - It should show a message similar to below

`Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mongod)`

`Active: active (running) since Thu 2015-09-03 04:57:49 IST; 7s ago`

Have detailed my steps in my **[blog post](https://rohan-paul.github.io/mongodb_in_ubuntu/2015/09/03/How_to_Install_MongoDB_Iin_Ubuntu-15.04.html)**.

Answer (score 1):

As I have said before:  The Debian/Ubuntu packages have been patched with systemd service units, to fill the hole left by the stuff that is published directly from mongodb.org.  But there's no shortage of `mongodb.service` unit files on the WWW.  It's not hard to write one, either.  (I have.)

Specifically: You'll find [such a service unit](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/vivid/mongodb/vivid/view/head:/debian/mongodb-server.mongodb.service) in [the mongodb-server version 2.6 package for Ubuntu version 15](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/mongodb-server).  There's also [a service unit published by mongodb.org](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/rpm/mongod.service), indeed.  It is simply the case that the mongodb.org people have mistakenly conflated the use of RPM with the use of systemd in the distribution-specific stuff.

Note that, ironically, the mongodb.org-supplied service units do not apply [the systemd service unit directives that mongodb.org itself recommends](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/ulimit/#linux-distributions-using-systemd).  Neither do the Debian/Ubuntu-supplied ones.  But, again: A hand-written service unit with these directives isn't hard to write; or indeed to modify to add things like numactl.  ☺

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/187540/5132
- https://askubuntu.com/a/617869/43344

Answer (score 0):

Well none of A.B's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/636125/1123) worked. So my only option was to install from the tarball

Follow, instructions on the docs related to this topic.

Answer (score 0):

As a short add-on to @A.B.'s excellent answer. On vivid amd64, with a **previous install of mongod 2.6**.26, simply replacing the existing `sources.list.d` file with

```
deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse
```

followed by a dist-upgrade worked automatically.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```