# MongoDB 3.0.2 won't start after upgrading to Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 15.10, mongodb

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 15.10 after which MongoDB 3.0.2 is not starting.

`$ sudo service mongod start`

which would throw error:

`Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service failed to load: No such file or directory.`

Answer (score 21):

It's just the lack of a service file for systemd. No need to go back to upstart like Kartik did or use a different repository than described in https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/installation/.

Create a file `/lib/systemd/system/mongodb.service` with the following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
After=network.target

[Service]
User=mongodb
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongodb.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: See also the note in http://askubuntu.com/a/617869/43344 .

Comment: I would add that you need to keep careful eye on file ownership of the data directory, the tmp fs lock and the log file. I was messing around trying to get this working and `sudo service...` was silently failing because of permissions issues

Comment: This is the right answer. Super clean! Does not require any package! Thanks!

Comment: for some reason the default config file is called `/etc/mongod.conf` and not `/etc/mongodb.conf`

Comment: @mightyuhu is correct, without the correct path defined I get failure.  with the correct path I don't get failure.

Comment: Thanks! This is the right answer.

One small thing: the service name should be `mongod` because this is what they use on their official site. So `mongodb.conf` should be `mongod.conf`  and the file name should be `/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service`

Answer (score 12):

This error occurred due to the problem with the new Ubuntu (15 and ahead).

Default init system is **systemd** which was **Upstart** previously.
So you need to install Upstart, reboot your system and here you go, you can now run mongodb service.

- Install Upstart

`sudo apt-get install upstart-sysv`

- Reboot your system

`sudo service mongod start`

`mongod start/running, process 3371`

Comment: The service name is now `mongodb`

Comment: @sowrov, no, the latest service name is still 'mongod'

Comment: after installing upstart-sysv, and rebooting my ubuntu 16.04 it went blank; I had to go in recovery and apt-get remove it. This thread might be helpful if you want to keep using upstart http://askubuntu.com/questions/760615/ubuntu-16-04lts-does-not-boot-after-package-upstart-sysv-is-installed

Answer (score 5):

I used debian package in ubuntu 15.10

```
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian wheezy/mongodb-org/3.0 main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues after upgrading to 15.10.

There could be a lot of issues but depending on what's caused your problem you may be able to get your mongodb running through init.d :

`sudo /etc/init.d/mongodb start`

That worked for me, but not a long term solution since you need to run that after every restart or add it to your startup tasks.  So I followed the following:

1) creating the service file as explained by 'sclausen'.

2) reload the service by running:

`sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

3) ran `sudo service mongodb start`

4) The command ran without output.  So I tested by running `mongo` and got a socket error:

`Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1062:14)`

5) Looked through the logs `tail -n 50 /var/log/mongodb/`  and found out the underlying error :

`2016-02-26T14:28:23.538+1100 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock errno:1 Operation not permitted`

6) deleted the problematic socket file:  `sudo rm /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock`
as suggested on this thread:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29813648/failed-to-unlink-socket-file-error-in-mongodb-3-0

7) re ran the service: `sudo service mongodb start`

at that point all was good and Bob returned to his rightful position as my uncle.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have Ubuntu 16.04.1, I was installing MongoDB 3.2.11, and I was getting that same error. After several cleaned ups and retry's, it finally worked "enabling" the service:

```
systemctl enable mongod.service
```

Then it just worked