# how should I move mongod from upstart preserving current database

Tags: systemd, mongodb

following this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617097/mongodb-2-6-does-not-start-on-ubuntu-15-04/617869#617869)

I have a mongod installed - that used upstarts to load up. 
now server is upgraded, and supports only systemd.

How do I move mongod to work with systemd - without loosing current databases/users/settings ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify what version of MongoDB you are using. Current versions of MongoDB ship with systemd service files, so there's no special work to make them work systemd.

Also, switching init systems does not affect the database data that MongoDB manages.

Comment: solution was to upgrade mongodb to 3.4